# Is it okay to use Firebase Cloud Messaging for B2B clients to reach end-users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, multi-tenant

I am looking to potentially use Firebase Cloud Messaging to flexibly add push notifications to my platform. The issue I am running into is that Firebase advises against sharing actual Firebase "projects" between "logically distinct apps."

For a normal multitenant SaaS offering, this would be a single project to represent all the client environments with end-users data being intermingled within a single location. In this case, we would logically (in our backend logic) prevent client's abilities to access each other's customer data.

The wrinkle comes in because we actually have individual, nearly identical application servers within our private AWS cluster (and databases) for each customer. We think this would work via still programmatically controlling access via each individual backend, allowing only the servers to communicate with the Firebase admin SDK.

Does anyone know if this is within the best practices? or does this violate the expected limitations?